# How do i get the android layout to redraw?

Tags: android

My android layout contains text fields that are populated upon opening the app.
The problem i'm having is layout doesn't redraw with the refreshed view until i press the text input box. The text fields populate immediately on touch.  How do i ensure the layout is refreshed automatically?

Comment: please share your layout and relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a view redraw itself call `invalidate` on it. But a TextView should do that automatically if the text is changed.

Comment: how would i invalidate() the layout?? or do i just call it on a text input

Comment: A new layout pass can be requested with `requestLayout`.